# 4k@60Hz via Docking station not working

Tags: display, display-resolution, monitor, 4k-monitor

Hello fellow Ubuntu users. I'm new to the Ubuntu-world and trying to set up my 4k monitor via a Lenovo docking station with 60Hz since 30Hz is unbearable.

I have a Lenovo T14s Gen 1 with USB-C connection to a [Lenovo ThinkPad USB-C Dock Gen2 Docking Station](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/acc500106-thinkpad-usb-c-dock-gen-2-overview-and-service-parts) which is connected to a [DELL S2721QS](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-27-4k-uhd-monitor-s2721qs/apd/210-axlg/monitors-monitor-accessories) monitor via DisplayPort. The cables are providing the necessary specs to support 4k@60Hz.

I tried all the option available [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=259408) but still couldn't get it to work properly. Do you have any suggestions what I could do?

Options I tried are e.g.:

```
➜  ~ cvt 3840 2160 50 
# 3840x2160 49.97 Hz (CVT 8.29M9) hsync: 111.17 kHz; pclk: 587.00 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160_50.00"  587.00  3840 4144 4560 5280  2160 2163 2168 2225 -hsync +vsync
➜  ~ cvt -r 3840 2160 60 
# 3840x2160 59.97 Hz (CVT 8.29M9-R) hsync: 133.25 kHz; pclk: 533.00 MHz
Modeline "3840x2160R"  533.00  3840 3888 3920 4000  2160 2163 2168 2222 +hsync -vsyn
```

When I reduced blanking @50Hz this is the output I get.

```
cvt 3840 2160 50 -r

ERROR: Multiple of 60Hz refresh rate required for  reduced blanking.
```

Do you have any suggestions what I could try??

Thanks so much
J